Upload middleware not executing upon being called by route
I'm making a fullstack mern application that features a form that should allow users to upload images. I've confirmed that the files are properly appended to the body of the request, but when the request reaches the endpoint its supposed to use the upload middleware to store the images in an s3 bucket. After debugging I realized that none of the code in the middleware is running. I checked the file path on the require statement so I'm not sure why the code isn't running.
const auth = require('../middleware/auth.js');
const upload = require('../middleware/upload.js');

// POST Route for event creation
router.post('/event', auth, upload.array('eventPhotos', 5), async (req, res) => {
  try {
      // Extract image URLs from the uploaded files
      const eventPhotos = req.files.map(file => file.location);

      const newEvent = {
          title: req.body.title,
          description: req.body.description,
          street: req.body.street,
          city: req.body.city,
          state: req.body.state,
          postalCode: req.body.postalCode,
          timezone: req.body.timezone,
          startDate_startTime: req.body.startDate_startTime,
          endDate_endTime: req.body.endDate_endTime,
          participants: req.body.participants,
          eventPhotos: eventPhotos,
          tickets: req.body.tickets, // Parse tickets from string to array if necessary
          attendantId: generateAttendantNumber(),
          eventId: uuidv4(),
          location: req.body.location
      };

      user.events.push(newEvent);
      await user.save();

      res.json({ 
          msg: 'Event created successfully', 
          eventUrl: `http://localhost:3000/payment/${newEvent.eventId}`, 
          attendantCode: newEvent.attendantId 
      });
  } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});


//upload.js
const multer = require('multer');
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const path = require('path');

// Configure AWS SDK
aws.config.update({
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
});

const s3 = new aws.S3();


// Configure Multer-S3
const upload = multer({ 
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
        acl: 'public-read', // Allows public read access to the uploaded files
        key: function ( file, cb) {
            cb(null, `${Date.now().toString()}-${file.originalname}`);
        },
    }),
    limits: { fileSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024 }, // Limit file size to 10MB
    fileFilter: function ( file, cb) {
        const ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
        if (ext !== '.jpg' && ext !== '.jpeg' && ext !== '.png') {
            return cb(new Error('Only images are allowed'), false);
        }
        cb(null, true);
    },
});

module.exports = upload;


Like I said I'm not sure its the file path and the client seems to pass the information on without issue. The specific error I got was:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
I figured out that this was because req.files was undefined, after that I realized that my middleware wasn't running at all.
Here's the server.js file as well
// server.js

const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const path = require('path');

// Routes
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users.js');
const publicRoutes = require('./routes/publicRoutes');
const protectedRoutes = require('./routes/protectedRoutes');

const app = express();

// Connect to MongoDB
connectDB();

// Middleware
app.use(cors()); // Enable CORS for all routes
app.use(express.json()); // Parse JSON bodies
app.use(cookieParser()); // Cookie monster

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

// Define routes
app.use('/api/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/api/public', publicRoutes); // Public routes
app.use('/api/protected', protectedRoutes); 
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));


app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client/build/index.html'));
});

// Define port
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, welcome to the API server!');
});

app.get('/success', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Purchase success');
});

app.get('/cancel', (req, res) => {
  res.send('>:( You canceled');
});

// Start server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});


